# Why is there no wait_event_..._irqsave() function or macro in the Linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, spinlock, irq

In the Linux kernel the function `wait_event_lock_irq(wq_head, condition, lock)` is provided in `include/linux/wait.h` that expects `lock` to be held and unlocks/locks it using `spin_lock_irq()` and `spin_unlock_irq()`.
Is there a particular reason that something along the lines of `wait_event_lock_irqsave()` that uses `spin_lock_irqsave()`/`spin_lock_irqrestore()` is not provided?

Answer (score 0):

`spin_lock_irqsave()` and `spin_unlock_irqrestore()` save and restore the CPU's "interrupts enabled" status flags. If you know you are not running in an interrupt context with interrupts enabled, but need to synchonize with locks taken in interrupt context, you can use `spin_lock_irq()` and `spin_unlock_irq()` to disable and re-enable interrupts without preserving ing the "interrupts enabled" status flags.

The `wait_event_...()` macros should *never* be called from an interrupt context (because they may sleep), so it is safe for them to assume that they are not called from an interrupt context, so there is no need to preserve the CPU's "interrupts enabled" status flags. The normal (non-IRQ) `wait_event_...()` macros should also *never* be called with interrupts disabled (again, because they may sleep), so it is safe for them to assume that interrupts are not disabled. Of course, the `wait_event_..._lock_irq()` macro *are* called with interrupts disabled, but they assume that interrupts were enabled before the preceding call to `spin_lock_irq()` and that interrupts can be safely re-enabled.

Comment: But interrupts can be disabled in a non-interrupt context, or we just don't know from where we were called. I think that's one of the primary reasons for using `spin_lock_irqsave()` over `spin_lock_irq()`.

Comment: @apriori Interrupts can be disabled in a non-interrupt context, but you cannot call the `wait_event_...()` macros with interrupts disabled because they may sleep and you are not allowed to sleep with interrupts disabled.

Comment: @apriori I've added a bit to the end of the second paragraph about why the `wait_event_...()` macros should never be called with interrupts disabled.

Comment: @apriori, Yes, I've added a bit about that too now, thanks. :)

Comment: We basically wrote the same thing there about the macro so I deleted my comment. :) Can we agree that the assumption "that interrupts were enabled before the preceding call to spin_lock_irq()" is a reasonable one for most applications but one could construct a use-case for a `wait_event_...()` macro that uses the `spin_lock_irqsave()` / `spin_unlock_irqrestore()` variants (even if only for code generalization / reuse purposes)?

Comment: @apriori Well, I think it's hard enough to pick the correct `wait_event_` macro already because there are so many of them without introducing unnecessary extras. There is nothing stopping you from calling `spin_lock_irqsave()` before `wait_event_..._lock_irq()` and `spin_unlock_irqrestore()` afterwards. Just don't expect the flags to be preserved inside the `wait_event_..._lock_irq()` macro as there really is no point doing so.